# How to make UDP sink and source run in a single flow graph in GNURadio?

Tags: ubuntu, udp, vlc, gnuradio

I tried to use UDP source and sink to control the VLC as on this example: http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gnu-radio-blog/320-a-simple-way-to-get-video-in-and-out-of-gnu-radio
[Gnuradio flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzUna.png)

The procedures:

1. open 2 instances of VLC in a single laptop. (to enable multiple instance in VLC:  Tools>Preferences > uncheck box 'Use only one instance..')
2. specify udp address (udp://:@5005) of instance 1 (sink)and click play. Use the other instance  (source) to stream video exactly like shown on the link
3. execute the gnuradio flowgraph like shown on the link

I expect to get streamed video from VLC instance 2 at instance 1, but i got nothing shown. It seems like the UDP source and sink in the flowgraph cannot be accessed by the VLC.

I tried to verify that the VLC is OK and able to stream by setting the UDP socket on both instances to the same port:

```
    instance1 -> udp://:@5005
    instance2 -> ip address: 127.0.0.1 ; port:5005

    The streamed video from VLC instance 2 succesfully shown on instance1.
```

So i guessed the problem must be from the UDP implementation in gnuradio. 
To validate this, I made another flowgraph as follows:

```
    signal_source->udp_sink
    udp_source->qt_gui_sink
```

I set both udp sink and source to the same port: 1234. I expect to get a waveform at the gui_sink, but i got nothing.

What i can see from this, is the UDP source and sink cannot work in a single flowgraph. So, the question is **how to make the UDP source and sink work in a single gnuradio flowgraph so that it can work in a single laptop?**

Im running  GNU Radio v3.7.9.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is not a networking/firewall issue? What IP address are you using in the Sink/source and VLC to send/listen to?

Comment: sorry for late response. i dont think its firewall issue coz i run sudo ufw status, its return inactive. I set exactly like shown in the link: UDP Source: 127.0.0.1, UDP Sink: 192.168.1.100

Comment: What a pity the link is broken...

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I could see is that you don't say if you set the configuration in the 2 VLC windows. You said that you set in one of then, but you need do the same in the VLC's window that you want to send the video. 
You can see how to do this in the video, but for me it's just because this configuration that your program doesn't work.
I hope you can resolve your problem.